# Get HTML attribute values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="block-a">
<label data-value="15" name=symptom">Group1</label>
<div class="clsfWrapper">
    <label data-value="10" name=clsfName"> SubHeader1</label>
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div class="ui-btn">
            <span>SelectedValue</span>
            <select class="selectClass">
            <option value="1">value1</option>
            <option value="2">value2</option>
            <option value="3">value3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clsfWrapper">
    <label data-value="11" name=clsfName"> SubHeader2</label>
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div class="ui-btn">
            <span>SelectedValue</span>
            <select class="selectClass">
            <option value="1">value1</option>
            <option value="2">value2</option>
            <option value="3">value3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="block-a">
<label data-value="16" name=symptom">Group2</label>
<div class="clsfWrapper">
    <label data-value="5" name=clsfName"> SubHeader1</label>
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div class="ui-btn">
            <span>SelectedValue</span>
            <select class="selectClass">
            <option value="1">value1</option>
            <option value="2">value2</option>
            <option value="3">value3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clsfWrapper">
    <label data-value="6" name=clsfName"> SubHeader2</label>
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div class="ui-btn">
            <span>SelectedValue</span>
            <select class="selectClass">
            <option value="1">value1</option>
            <option value="2">value2</option>
            <option value="3">value3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
</body>
```

What is the best way to find every select SubHeader and Group value? For example the first one:
Group value: 15
Subheader value: 10
Option value : 1

and second one:
Group value: 15
Subheader value: 11
Option value : 1

I have a very robust way to get those values and i was wondering if there was any easier and more certain way.
jQuery:

```
function getHtmlAttributes(){
$.each($('#page_visit_reg_new_colds_2 option:selected'), function(key, value){
    var optionParent = $(this).parent();
    var selectParent = optionParent.parent();
    var divParent1 = selectParent.parent();
    var divParent2 = divParent1.parent();
    var subheaderName = divParent1.parent().find('label[name=clsfName]').data('value');
    var groupName = divParent2.parent().find('label[name=symptom]').data('value');
});
```

**EDIT** Changed label value to data-value

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why are labels holding values, and are you able to change the markup at all?

Comment: I also realized that labels holding values could be wrong. However i have to assign a text with certain value, which i retrieve from server. 
I am using jQuery mobile and found from API that i could replace label with data-label (http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/).
I can do minor changes to markup. wrapper divs are neccessary. 
Still the main question is: Is there any better solution to get attibute values without using those parent() methods?
@Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instead of going from the option and then with parent up to the group, will start from the block and go down to the selected option.

It is still cycling trough the elements but is not using `parent()`

```
$.each($('.block-a'), function(){   
    var groupName = $(this).find("label[name='symptom']").data('value');
    $.each($(this).find(".clsfWrapper"), function(){ 
         var subheaderName = $(this).find("label[name='clsfName']").data('value');                  
        $.each($(this).find('select option:selected'), function(){ 
            var optionvalue = $(this).val();
        });
    });
});
```

On the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1d18rd2/2/) i've added console log so you can check if everything is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the data attribute, just use this jQuery syntax:

```
$("#elementName").data("DataAttribute");
```

To get the value from the following label (IDs are better than names):

```
<label data-value="11" id="clsfName"> SubHeader2</label>
```

Use this:

```
var dataValue = $("#clsfName").data("value");
```

Comment: I can't use id's for labels. var dataValue = $('label[name=clsfName]').data("value") also didn't work as neccessary.

Comment: If you can't use IDs, you will need to traverse the DOM.  Using find() is preferable to parent() since it is easier to read, but it's still pretty messy.  I would start with:

$("div .clsfWrapper").each(function(){ put your $(this).find() logic here });